# How are poisons handled in the d6 system?

Tags: poison, d6-system

I've tried to search for but didn't find anything exactly in the OGL rules about how poisons are handled. Are there any rules there?

Comment: Which part of poison handling are you looking for?

Comment: everything as I didnt see anything there (only at the skills I saw "fortitude to resist poisons" and uhm.....nothing more found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the D6 Adventure book on page 80 under Stamina (Physique) it goes into how to handle poisons.

> To avoid the effects of a toxin (inhaled, ingested, or absorbed) or disease (encountered in any manner), a character makes a stamina roll. ( e first attempt after initial exposure does not count as an action; subsequent attempts to resist the toxin do.) Several factors figure into the difficulty of the attempt, including the deadliness and dosage of the poison in question. For example, a fatal bout of botulism has a difficulty of 9, while a killing dose of cyanide has a difficulty of 42.

This was the only entry directly I could find on it.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent ["REUP" core book](http://www.starwarstimeline.net/WestEndGames/The%20Roleplaying%20Game%20Revised%20Expanded%20Updated%20WRP.pdf) has some poisoning rules.
Under Miscellaneous Damage (p 102):
4D for Food Poisoning (very severe case)
8D+2 for General Poison (fatal dose)

And there are richer "optional rules" beginning on p 103. Excerpts:

> the poisoner must make a Moderate first aid roll (or a Very Easy (A)
>   medicine roll) as above. He must also make an alien species roll and
>   check on the following table to establish the poison’s effectiveness

---

> The victim takes one Wound every turn, until he has either taken the
>   full damage or is dead

---

> A Moderate (A) medicine or difficult first aid roll allows a person
>   analyzing a poison to identify a specific type of poison

---

> Once the poison is identified, the character may use the poison kit or
>   the contents of a medpac to neutralize the poison (the difficulty of
>   the skill roll is equal to the poison’s damage when using (A)
>   medicine, and the damage +5 when using first aid)

---

There are also rules for Illness and Disease on the following page, which may be useful in similar situations.